# acyclic in chord graph and elimination ordering in chordal bipartite graph

Tags: graphs

From wiki, "a chord graph is one in which all cycles of four or more has a chord." My first question is if a graph is acyclic, i.e., there is no cycle in the graph, can it be called as a chord graph?

Another question is about elimination ordering in chordal bipartite graph. It is well known that in a chordal bipartite graph, given $x_1<x_2$, $y_1<y_2$ and $(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1)\in E$, then $(x_2,y_2)\in E$. But given a chordal graph $G$, if we add in $G$ vertices $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ where $x_1<x_2$, $y_1<y_2$ and edges $(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1)$, is $G$ still a chordal bipartite graph?

Comment: Yes, trees are chordal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has little to do with computer science. Perhaps it should be asked on Mathematics instead.

Comment: Also, please stick to one question per post.